# Let $(X,d)$ be any metric space. Show that if $F\subset X$ is closed, then $F^c$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Not sure if this proof is correct.

Suppose that $F⊂X$ is closed. Let $x∈F^c$ so $x∉F$. Since $x∈F^c$ , then the neighborhood $N(x)\cap F=∅$. Thus $N(x)\cap F^c≠∅$ so $x∈F^c$ must be an interior point of $F^c$. Thus $F^c$ is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct.

First of all, you need to supply the argument that "Since $F$ is closed and $x\not\in F$, hence $x$ is not a limit point of $F$ and therefore there exists a neighbourhood of $x$ which doesn't intersect $F$".

Next, $N(x)\cap F^c\neq\emptyset$ doesn't imply that $x$ is an interior point of $F^c$, you need $N(x)\subset F^c$, and that is exactly what follows from $N(x)\cap F=\emptyset $

Hope it helps:)

Comment: so because ()⊂ , that means that Fc is open?

Comment: Yes, because definition of open set $X$ is that $"\forall x\in X\exists\ \  nbd \ \ \ N(x) \ \ \ such\ \ \ that\ \ \ N(x)\subset X"$.